# Javascript associate array gives many undefined fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an associate array with the key is the Id of the item. For example, the item id is 104, therefore the id of the object will be array[104] = {item.info};

So I have this in my component, but every time I am outputting my array it shows 1-103 values and all of them are null. How would I get rid of it and make the array output only what is stored.

Comment: Use an object instead of an array.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. It has arrays, whose indexes start at 0, and objects, with arbitrary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not have associative array like in PHP.

What JavaScript has that is most similar to associative array is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). The difference is that an object is not iterable, while an associative array is iterable.

What you currently do is basically:

```js
const data = [];  // [] is an array

data[10] = {
  item: 1
};

console.log(data);
```

What you need to do should be something like this:

```js
const data = {};  // {} is an object

data[10] = {
  item: 1
};

console.log(data);
```

When you do `json_encode()` in PHP, it is actually converting associative array into a JSON, which is a valid JavaScript object, which do not support associative array as well.

So what it does would be something like this:

```php
$data = [
  '10' => [
    'item' => 1
  ]
];

echo json_encode($data);

// output => { "10": { "item": 1 } }
```

Notice the `{}` syntax instead of `[]` syntax.

Answer (score -2):

array doesn't have key, value. it just have value
if you use key, value data form, you should use object

```
let item = {104: item.info}
```

how to use object :

```
item[104]
```

Comment: what's the output of  `Object.keys([0,0,0,0,0])` ... so, Array's have keys

Comment: In javascript Array is part of Object. so  `Object.keys([0,0,0,0,0])` has result. but in that case `[0,0,0,0,0]` is looked as Object.  Array don't have key. it have `index`